# Vertical News feed design

Tags: css, html, feed

Would anyone be able to explain how the CSS and HTML markup would look for a vertical news feed design like: http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/41027/screenshots/619599/attachments/51139/TheSecret_Concept.png

I really like the icons + line with text on the right side.  I know CSS has the content attribute I can add a symbol and use border for the vertical line but I was wondering how it may be possible to use images/bootstrap icons instead of declaring the symbol in CSS.

Any tips or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: view source ? you'll get the code...

Comment: It's a concept image...

Comment: try coding something then come up with some code when you are stuck , nobody is going to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This is some truly horrific CSS, for which I should probably be shot, however, it seems to be vaguely something like you posted. That is; assuming this is what you were talking about.
```

Anyway, assuming you're talking about those little pieces of text by Zane David or whoever, with the icon on the side and a line running through the icons, here is my terrible attempt at doing it with an unordered list with modified bullets and an hr running through them. The

---

is definitely not the ideal option, however, I think the ul with li's with custom bullets is the right way to go. Excuse the leaves by the way.

http://jsbin.com/efiveq/1

If you completely ignore my horrible positioning and such, you should still be able to see that an unordered list is probably the best way to go.

Edit: switch out the code for .news-feed .well:after with:

`.news-feed .well:after {
content:"";
position: absolute;
top: 60%;
left: 5px;
border-top: 20px solid #A5A5A5;
border-top-color: inherit;
border-left: 20px solid transparent;
border-right: 20px solid transparent;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);`

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the start! I came up with this but any idea how I can align the chat bubble's triangle with the side of the box?

http://jsfiddle.net/eKTsq/1/

Comment: I can't seem to access it, could you do it in a jsbin?

Comment: Sorry, here's a jsbin version: http://jsbin.com/icumaj/2/

Comment: @MCG Apologies for such a long wait, edited with code modification.

Answer (score 0):

What you have asked here needs few certain couple of pages to explain things.
What I can suggest you is to go through the following Youtube tutorials to learn how to handle images with css.
Once you watch these videos and practice them, you will be able to design much better than the elements in the image you have uploaded in your question.

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJ5CiFCpErE
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM6i5WglYbs
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpObCDzAOIU

You should probably watch similar videos IF NEEDED :)